# Steering wheel with optical or multiturn

Tags: wheel

i have a logitech formula force feedback wheel , and i'd like to change the rotation of wheel from 180 to 900. I know that i have to change the pot, but i don't know what type of pot i should use. I've been thinking in using an optical one, but i don't have any ideea how to do it. I could also use a multi turn one but i know these things aren't so strong.If someone can explain how and what should i use step by step i'll be thankfull. And sorry for my english ;)

Comment: Could you please clarify the question? As I understand it, your steering wheel is capable of physically making infinite number of rotations but signal wise only responds from -180 to 180 degrees. You would like to expand it's signal range from -900 to +900. Perhaps you're working on a truck simulator of sorts.

Also, what are the physical characteristics inside the wheel? Would it be as simple as attaching a 5:1 gear mechanism to the wheel and wiring the original pot to that?

Comment: Yeah i'd like to expand the signal range from -900 to +900. No is not that simple. Here are some pics about the physical characteristics : http://i57.tinypic.com/34ditjm.jpg  http://i58.tinypic.com/1zmmelt.jpg And is not capable of infinite number of rotation , only 180 degrees but i can modify that easily .

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications. For future use, I don't recommend tinypic. If possible embed the pictures in your original post. I believe you can do that after you gain a certain reputation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend trying one of these [360 degreee continuous angle sensors](http://www.digikey.com/product-search/en?pv1816=63&FV=fff4001e%2Cfff803d4&mnonly=0&newproducts=0&ColumnSort=0&page=1&quantity=0&ptm=0&fid=0&pageSize=25). Current technologies for angle sensing revolve around optical, resistive and hall effect properties as you identified. Generally, the highest end products use hall effect as it is completely analog and non-contacting. Building a sensor from scratch can be very difficult to optimize so I would recommend one of the packaged solutions and feed that to a microcontroller of your choice.